# php number_format not working in PHP version 5.4.22

Tags: php

I have been using following function for long time & it was working fine.. 
Now when i checked my site, Entire Number output is not working

What I tried is (was working fine earlier)

```
<?php 
$money_balance=1000000;
print number_format($money_balance,",");
?>
```

Expected out put is

> **1,000,000**

I don't know why it is not working now in Chrome and Firefox.
I am using **php 5.4.22**

Comment: there is no need to down vote this question... it was working an year ago !! You may need to find out this. Probably due to php version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/number_format) expects the second parameter to be an integer representing the number of digits to be displayed after the decimal point. Your code should look like this:

```
<?php 
  $money_balance=1000000;
  print number_format($money_balance,0);
?>
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yRcYjh)